# Why is zina forbidden?

Tags: zina

I would like to know the exact reason for zina being forbidden. Also how can i advice someone who has so much desire for zina ?

Comment: If zina is allowed, how will you determine your father, genealogy, family structure all will be put into chaos, I'm not going deep into problems of inheritance, and other mahram issues. Would you like it for your mother or sister, if answer is no then others also dont like zina on part of sisters and mothers

Comment: You will find plenty of reason to not do Zina, but can you give me a single reason why it should be permitted, except your nafs say's it do so? if Zina is permitted then, there is no father, mother, sister, brother relation, there will be no family, no sweet home nothing will be there..just all will live a life like an animal does. so there will be no difference between a human and an animal.. But as A Muslim our only reason should be Zina is forbidden in the Quran and Hadith and it's a big sin.

Comment: Jazakallahu khair for all. May Allah grant you all the jannathul firdaus- aameen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zina is forbidden because Allah has explicitly forbidden it in the Qur'an:

> ولا تقربوا الزنا إنه كان فاحشة وساء سبيلا
>
> And do not approach *zina* (unlawful sexual intercourse). Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way.
>
> — [Al-'Isra' 32](https://legacy.quran.com/17/32)

If Allah's supreme authority is not good enough for your friend, trying to find weaker arguments that might convince them is probably just a waste of time.

Comment: Jazakallahu khair. May Allah grant you the jannathul firdaus- aameen